# Smallest enclosing cylinder

Tags: geometry, nonlinear-optimization, computational-geometry, packing-problem

I have a set of 3D points that *approximately* lie on a cylinder. This cylinder is straight and can be oriented in any direction. I would like to compute the minimal enclosing cylinder for the set; that is, I would like to find the cylinder with the smallest radius (I do not care about the height) that encloses all the points.

In the case of enclosing circles and spheres, I have read that there exists a nice efficient algorithm by Emo Welzl ( [Smallest enclosing disks(balls and ellipsoids)](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/PublFiles/SmallEnclDisk_LNCS555_91.pdf) ). For cylinders I just found the question [Smallest enclosing cylinder for an irregular body](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86127/smallest-enclosing-cylinder-for-an-irregular-body), where it seems that the cylinder could be obtained using nonlinear optimization tools.

Can this smallest enclosing cylinder problem be solved without using nonlinear optimization, as in the case of balls?

---

EDIT: What if I have a good initial guess of the axis of the cylinder? I mean, what if I have to obtain the cylinder with its axis close to a given direction?

Comment: This is interesting -- but minimization problems are not my forte. However: 1) only the points on the convex hull of the set matters (because the others are always within any cylinder that encloses the whole set), and 2) you are looking for translation $\vec{t}$ and rotation $\theta, \varphi$, that transform the set to within a minimal-radius disk on the $xy$ plane. Thus, five free variables. Most difficult case: a minimum-radius cylinder with radius greater than height (even if height not relevant here); makes set analysis for best orientation difficult.

Comment: Make that "with *diameter* greater than height", since the problematic range is $\sqrt{1/2} \le h \le 2r$. If you restrict the point set fit to cylinders with height greater than twice the radius, the highest distance between the points on the convex hull of the point set is roughly/somewhat aligned with the cylinder axis.

Answer (score 0):

It is non-linear optimization.
Take a look at the software CYL at:
http://petitjeanmichel.free.fr/itoweb.petitjean.freeware.html
(free binaries)

Comment: This looks like a comment and not an answer.